# cant save django model

Tags: python, ajax, django

I send data from html fields via AJAX

```
    var dataToSend = { some1 : $('.name1').html().replace(/[\n\r]/g, '').trim(),
                       some2 : $('.name2').html().replace(/[\n\r]/g, '').trim(),
                       some3 : $('.name3').html().replace(/[\n\r]/g, '').trim(),
                       some4 : $('.name4').html().replace(/[\n\r]/g, '').trim() }
    if (dataToSend) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'do/smth',
                    data: dataToSend,
                    async: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function() {
                        alert('draft is saved')
                    }
                });
            }
```

Then i receive POST request which does contain data but my model saves only when all arguments are existing, so for example if i get only {some1:"value1",some2:"value2"} my django view WONT save it.

The question is: how can i possibly save data into db, if my fields are empty, as you can see i have `blank=True` in my model, but it does not help

**model**

```
class Draft(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(_('company name'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    pitch = models.CharField(_('pitch'), max_length=140, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(_('url'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    thesis = models.TextField(_('thesis'), blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views**

```
def save_from_ajax_post(request):
    data = dict(request.POST.items())
    draft = Draft.objects.create(data)
    draft.save()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 1}), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: `Draft.objects.create(**data)` should be used, as the values are expected to be passed as keyword arguments.

Comment: this is solution, thanks